# Azure Pipeline with Scheduled trigger triggers on every commit

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want a pipeline to trigger every six months. It s a compliance requirement for code scanning.
So I created a schedule:

```
schedules:
  - cron: "0 0 1 */6 *"

    branches:
     include:
       - master
    always: true
```

But this pipeline is triggering on every commit to master. It is my understanding that it should not.
Did I not understand the scheduled trigger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on my test, I could reproduce the similar issue.

When I commit changes to master, the build reason is CI Trigger.

[image]

You could try to add the `trigger: none` in your yaml file. Then you could [disable the CI Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#opting-out-of-ci).

Here is an example:

```
trigger: none

schedules:
  - cron: "0 0 1 */6 *"
    branches:
     include:
       - master
    always: true
```